# compareTo() method using float attribute of object. How is it used, and why?

Tags: java, compareto

The code from my class, I don't understand it totally. I read on internet that compareTo() method is used for comparing strings to strings and objects to strings,but in my code it is used to compare float to strings, I guess?! Can you explain how is used comparedTo() method in the code below and why do we use it in our case?

```
package ro.ase.acs.classes;

import ro.ase.acs.interfaces.Mobility;
//Comparable is a generic interface; click add unimplemented methods ; the method will appear at the end of the class
public final class Car extends Vehicle implements Mobility, Cloneable,Comparable<Car> {
    public static final int maxNbOfKm = 1_000_000;//it is static, in order to acces it use .
    private EngineType engineType;
    private float speed;

    public Car() {
        super();
        engineType = EngineType.gas;
        speed = 0;
    }

    public Car(String _name, EngineType _engineType, float _speed) {
        super(_name, true);
        engineType = _engineType;
        speed = _speed;
    }

    @Override
    public void Start() {
        System.out.println("The " + engineType.toString() +
                " car has started!");
    }

    @Override
    public void Stop() {
        System.out.println("The " + engineType.toString() +
                " car has stopped!");
    }

    @Override
    public void DisplaySpeed() {
        System.out.println(String.format("The %s car runs with %f km/h",
                engineType.toString(), speed));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("The car named ");
        sb.append(name);
        sb.append(" has a(n) ");
        sb.append(engineType.toString());
        sb.append(" engine and is running with ");
        sb.append(speed);
        sb.append(" km/h");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        Car c = (Car)super.clone();
        c.engineType = engineType;
        c.speed = speed;
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(!(obj instanceof Car)) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            Car c = (Car)obj;
            return name.equals(c.name);
        }
    }

@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return 31*name.hashCode()+13*(HasEngine()?1:0)+7*engineType.hashCode()+(int)speed*100;
}


    public enum EngineType { gas, diesel, electric, hybrid }



    @Override
    public int compareTo(Car o) {
        if(speed==o.speed)
        {return 0;}
        else if (speed>o.speed)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {return -1;}




    }

//  public final int hashCode() {
    //  return engineType.hashCode();
//  };
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: learn about java naming convents. Method names go camelCase, and that practice of using _param in constructors is (for good or bad) considered bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **contract** of the Comparable interface, respectively the `compareTo()` method is:

- it returns 0 when both objects are considered "the same" from an ordering perspective
- it returns -1 respectively +1 (to be precise any negative or positive value) to indicate when the "other" object is less respectively greater than "this" object.

In other words: the method provides a mean to define a **natural** order of objects that can be ordered.

If ordering cars by their speed actually makes sense is a completely different story. I would argue that: *no*, that doesn't make sense. If at all, you could/should define *external* Comparator objects that define different ways of "ordering" cars, and then a SpeedComparator would obviously order by speed (but in an explicit way).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what you compare, you can resolve which comes first and which second by what you define. In compareTo methods, -1 means that it comes first and the element you compare it to, comes after that. 1 means that it comes after the element and 0 means they are equal and doesn't get rearranged.

If speed is bigger then it comes later in your list, if it's smaller it comes after. Strings are compared by length for example, if you do "Chicken".compareTo("Cow") then chicken comes after.

Answer (score 1):

`compareTo()` method is used to sort object of a specific class.
In your case it compares `Car` objects by value of their `speed` property.

So you can use it to sort list (or array) of `Car` objects by values of their `speed` property.